# Sticky top-bar in Zurb Foundation 5 doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

On the documentation here http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html, it says that I should wrap my top-bar `<nav>` in a div with the class `contain-to-grid sticky`. My IDE has class auto-completion so I kinda figured out that `contain-to-grid` class is there but the `sticky` class doesn't seem to exist. As a result, since it's calling a non-existing class, the top-bar just acts as a regular one.

To clarify I am not looking for an immediately fixed top-bar. What I'm aiming for is when I scroll down the page and it went past the position of the top-bar, only then will it stick to the top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky"> <!-- This doesn't seem to work. -->
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-9 column">
        <p>Main body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 column">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi you can post more code and some example on jsfiddle will be better

Comment: Updated with the code. I can't seem to access jsfiddle right now but that's pretty much it. I just downloaded Foundation an hour or so ago.

Comment: This is a known issue right now with the current Repo, most of the custom installs of 5.0.2 have the stick top bar causing errors on every mouse scroll. We're waiting on a fix from Zurb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a typo in the minified JS.

Search for `stick_topbar` and replace with `sticky_topbar` in foundation.min.js

It was fixed almost 2 weeks ago and will be released with 5.0.3 https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/5022d75753ea01688aae531d8790b7895cb777c1

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, I just downloaded Foundation 5 and sticky bar option doesn't work.

Here's the output of Firebug console using the minified foundation.js :

```
this.settings.sticky_topbar is undefined
```

When I use the non-minifed version, the error disappear, however sticky doesn't work too with it.

If someone has a fix it would be really great :) !

Comment: Edit : I used the same markup as Propeller for my nav.
Class shown in the Foundation documentation : 'contain-to-grid sticky'